# Tomcat server not starting, possible misconfiguration of server xml?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I wrote really basic code. And The servlet is possibly the issue because, otherwise tomcat starts perfectly and reaches the index.html

I have configured tomcat with eclipse IDE. I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFkbV.png) error when I try to start with my servlet.

The stacktrace is

```java
Jun 28, 2019 1:41:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start

java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component 

[StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/User_Test_Series-1]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
```

My xml configuration

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>User_Test_Series-1</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>jdbc.Registration</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Registration</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Registration</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask you're probably new and you are looking for a quick solution. But please do read this to know more about how to ask perfect question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example refer this link on how to post a minimal reproducible and complete example

Comment: Few things you can try
1. Check the class and its package.
2. Lower case url pattern

Comment: did, but no change in problem